# Does Stunnel support non-encrypt connection?

Tags: ssl, fix-protocol, stunnel

1 question about Stunnel. I would like to use Stunnel as a FIX (Financial Information eXchange) gateway for internet, to support both SSL and non-SSL connection. Is Stunnel able to do without any encryption? I just had a try with plain socket but it looked Stunnel rejected the connection saying 'invalid protocol' or something.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with a non-encrypted Stunnel? Are you after using SSL/TLS without encryption or are you after a simple TCP relay of some sort?

Comment: Hi Bruno, what I want to do is just to run it as a gateway, route the incoming TCP msg to aonther ip/port.

Comment: I've just voted to move this to SuperUser, since this isn't really a programming-related question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to use SSL/TLS without encryption using cipher suites with null encryption (e.g. `TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA`), which are normally disabled by default, but could be set via the `ciphers` option of Stunnel. However, you would still be using SSL/TLS, which isn't what you seem to be looking for.

It looks like you're more generally looking for what's usually called a *TCP bouncer*. You should be able to find a number of implementations around.

Comment: Bruno, could you please recommend a solution of 'TCP bouncer'? I searched a lot, it looks few result with it.

Comment: Not sure, it depends on your environment. There are multiple forms of "TCP bouncing": it can be done via a router similarly to "reverse NAT" solutions (e.g. via `ipchains`), via independent applications, or via SSH (which would also secure the section of the connection that's using SSH).